# HOw to make sonic shader in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

[image]

I am trying to make a shader like the blue shader below but can’t get it right. I have tried using a mix shader with two diffuse and a fresnel but it ends up way off from the what I’m trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of this picture?
I tryed to make it. just you need little more dark blue.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is perfect but could you link me the image texture you used.

Comment: Here: http://prntscr.com/khz6zk